# How to allow a "?" character in a route parameter in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes, character, yaml

I would like to know how to allow a "?" character in a route parameter in Symfony2. This is the route that I have (actually, the route parameter I am focusing on is "messtext"):

```
ikproj_groupe_sendreply1:
pattern:  /{groupid}/{receiver}/{messtext}/{cible}/sendreply
defaults: { _controller: IkprojGroupeBundle:Messages:SendReply1 }
requirements:
    messtext: .+
```

In fact, I had a look at this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html which is about how to allow a "/" character in a route parameter in Symfony2. I did what I learnt from that tutorial exactly but the problem is that it doesn't work: Symfony2 still displays this error message: 
No route found for "GET /groupe/sendreply/11/28/hello,%20dear%20sir...can%20I%20join%20your%20group"

So, my questions are: what is wrong in my code above and how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 parameter of your route may accept '/' character. And this MUST be the last one as every following one are considered as part of the param value... In your case, Symfony routing never detect `cible` and `sendreply` parts of the URL.

Try to put `messtext` param at the very end of the URL :

```
ikproj_groupe_sendreply1:
pattern:  /{groupid}/{receiver}/{cible}/sendreply/{messtext}
defaults: { _controller: IkprojGroupeBundle:Messages:SendReply1 }
requirements:
    messtext: .+
```

Comment: Well, I made such change and I put messtext param the last one, but Symfony still display this error message: No route found for "GET /groupe/sendreply/11/28/P/" (from "http://localhost/Wkayet_project/PFESymfony2/web/app_dev.php/groupe/11/Groupe") ... By the way, the value that I would like to pass through the parameter `messtext` is: `???`. Therefore, it is obvious that Symfony still doesn't allow the "?" in the route parameter in this case. So, what would be the solution?...do you have any idea??

Comment: well, for example, in case when the parameter `messtext` contain the following value: `???`, how shall encode it with urlencode? could you give me just a simple example?..thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code that you creates the URL (PHP or Twig);

Comment: and sendreply is misplaced according to error you mentioned

Comment: `var groupid = 11; var receiver = 28; var messtext = "hello, can I join your group??"; var cible = "G"; var sendreplypath = "{{ path

('ikproj_groupe_sendreply1', {groupid: "PLACEHOLDER", receiver: "PLACEHOLDER2", messtext: "PLACEHOLDER3", cible: "PLACEHOLDER4"} ) }}"; sendreplypath = 

sendreplypath.replace("PLACEHOLDER", groupid); sendreplypath = sendreplypath.replace("PLACEHOLDER2", receiver); sendreplypath = sendreplypath.replace

("PLACEHOLDER3", messtext); sendreplypath = sendreplypath.replace("PLACEHOLDER4", cible); $.fancybox.open({href: sendreplypath,type: 'iframe'}); });`

Comment: As you can notice from the code above that the variable `messtext` contains a string which contains the "?" character ("hello, can I join your group??"). 
Actually I aim to pass the values of the variables: `groupid`, `receiver`, `messtext`, `cible ` to a fancybox window. This is the route that I have:

Comment: `ikproj_groupe_sendreply1:
    pattern:  /sendreply/{groupid}/{receiver}/{cible}/{messtext}
    defaults: { _controller: IkprojGroupeBundle:Messages:SendReply1 }
    requirements:
        messtext: .+`

Comment: This is the code of the function in the controller:

Comment: `public function SendReply1Action(Request $request, $groupid, $receiver, $messtext, $cible) {
        $message = new Messages();
        $form = $this->createForm(new MessagesType(), $message);
        return $this->render('IkprojGroupeBundle:Messages:SendReply.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'groupid' => $groupid,
            'receiver' => $receiver,
            'messtext' => $messtext,
            'cible' => $cible
        ));
    }`

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<script>
var groupid = {{groupid}};
var receiver = {{receiver}};
var messtext = "{{messtext}}";
var cible = "{{cible}}";
alert(messtext);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>`

Comment: By the way, once the fancybox window is displayed, an alert box will be displayed containing the value of the variable `messtext` which is supposed to be "hello, can I join your group??" but what it displays is the following message: "hello, can I join your group" (without the two interrogation marks "??"). I really wonder why...do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: @Nadim2014 all updates (specially about code) needs to be added to the question and not to the comments (then delete all comments)

Comment: @gp_sflover: I asked a question about such problem today, please have a look at this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884580/a-string-containing-is-not-displayed-correctly-in-a-fancybox-window-when-it?noredirect=1#comment42326198_26884580](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884580/a-string-containing-is-not-displayed-correctly-in-a-fancybox-window-when-it?noredirect=1#comment42326198_26884580)